# relationship between locales and glibc/locale-aware binaries

Tags: debian, locale

When I enable or disable locales in `/etc/locale.gen` configuration file, then I need to execute `locale-gen`. Looks like `locale-gen` processes enabled locale files(or locale template files?) for enabled locales in `/usr/share/i18n/locales/` directory. Does it produce some kind of binary file? How does this affect the `glibc` or locale-aware binaries? Am I correct that `glibc` and locale-aware binaries use the locales based on the variables seen in the output of `locale` command?

Comment: `locale-gen` updates file `/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does it produce some kind of binary file?

Yes, typically `/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive`.

> How does this affect the glibc or locale-aware binaries?

Usually they will fall back to the standard locale (called "C" or "POSIX") which does not require a `locale-archive` file.

> Am I correct that glibc and locale-aware binaries use the locales based on the variables seen in the output of locale command?

Yes. You can set separate locales for displaying monetary values `LC_MONETARY`, etc. But the main variable that acts as a default if the others aren't set is `LANG`. `locale` just reports what your current environment variables are implying.